# No main methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file error

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to complete this program for a java class that I am taking and it compiles completely fine but when i go to run the program it says "No main methods, applets, or MIDlets found in file." Anyone able to tell me why this is? Thanks.

public class BabysittingJob {

```
private int jobNumber;
private int babysitterCode;
private String babysitter;
private int childrenNumber;
private int hoursWorked;
private double fee;

public BabysittingJob(int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter) {
    year = year % 2000;
    this.childrenNumber = childrenNumber;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.babysitterCode = babysitterCode;
    this.jobNumber = ((year * 10000) + sequentialNumber);

    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        this.babysitter = "Cindy";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 2) {
        this.babysitter = "Greg";
    } else if (babysitterCode == 3) {
        this.babysitter = "Marcia";
    }

    if (babysitterCode == 1) {
        this.fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber == 1) {
        this.fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
    } else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber > 1) {
        this.fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any other classes in your program? If so, do any of them have a method named `static void main`?

Comment: I have the public class BabysittinJob. I do not have any named static void main. When I added that I got a bunch of errors when compiling.

Comment: Every Java program needs a method with that name somewhere, because that is how the program knows what do in the beginning: it calls main. If main is missing, it doesn't know where to start, so you will need to add it back in and work through those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a main method. This is what the compiler will start with. In the same class you can create a method that says public static void main(string args []){}. That or in a separate class with a main method you can create an instance of this class with BabysittingJob varName = new BabysittingJob(int, int, int, int, int, string);